# How can I use (Populate/item.source) 2 ListViews with 2 differents BindingContext in same ContentView

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, binding

I'm trying to populate  2 listviews from differents ViewModels and differents Models.

I tried to use Itemsource between 2 bindingcontext. (See my view.cs)

I try to use a name in my view and send a source as a sample in [xamarin forum].[1](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/120478/binding-multiple-viewmodels-in-xaml)

I try, the basic, to use in my Binding a Source={x:Reference Model.Protocol}

Anyone work

My view is:
XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="H2XA.View.ConnectView"
             x:Name="Root">
<!--I put a name where but i don't know if I can cuz i use Detail=new ConnectView every time -->
    <ContentPage.Content >
        <Grid >
            <!-- Código principal-->
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout  VerticalOptions="Start" >
                    <!--Exame -->
                    <Button x:Name="ConfigExam"  
                            Text="Características de exame" 
                            Clicked="ConfigExam_Clicked"
                            BackgroundColor="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                    <StackLayout x:Name="AllConfigExam"  VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  >
                        <Button x:Name = "NewProtocol"
                                Text="Criar novo protocolo" 
                                Clicked="NewProtocol_Clicked"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <BoxView />
                        <StackLayout x:Name="ProtoScreen" VerticalOptions="Start" >
                             <ListView x:Name="Protocol_Disponivel"  ItemSelected="OnSelectionP" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" >
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ViewCell>
                                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                                <MenuItem Text="Editar" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                          Clicked="EditarProtocol_Clicked" />
                                                <MenuItem Text="Remover" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                          Clicked="RemoverProtocol_Clicked" />
                                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                            <StackLayout Padding="5,0,5,0">
                                                <Label Text="Intervalos de tempo:" />
                                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <Label Text="0 | "/>
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Model.Patient.intervaldescription,Source={x:Reference Root}}" Font="14" />
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </ViewCell>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <!--Conexão -->
                    <Button x:Name="ConfigConn"  
                            Text="Aparelhos" 
                            Clicked="ConfigConn_Clicked"
                            BackgroundColor="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                    <StackLayout x:Name="AllConfigConn"  VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
                    
                        <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="Center" >
                        
                            <StackLayout Padding="10,10,10,10" VerticalOptions="Start">
                                <Button x:Name="connection"  
                                         Text="Procurar bluetooth" 
                                         Clicked="connection_Clicked"
                                         HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                <Label x:Name="Status_recebimento_N" 
                                        Text="Status"
                                                                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                <Label x:Name="Status_recebimento" 
                                        Text="{Binding Connectionwaymsg,Mode=Default}"
                                                                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout x:Name="ConnScreen" VerticalOptions="Start">
                            <Label x:Name="MAC_title" 
                                    Text="MAC do aparelho"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                            <ListView x:Name="MACS_Disponiveis"  ItemSelected="OnSelectionD" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" >
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ViewCell>
                                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                                <MenuItem Text="Renomear" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                          Clicked="ReplaceMAC_Clicked" />
                                                <MenuItem Text="Remover" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                          Clicked="RemoveMAC_Clicked" />
                                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                            <StackLayout Padding="5,0,5,0">
                                                <Label Text="MAC:" />
                                                <Label Text="{Binding .}" Font="14" />
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </ViewCell>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <!-- Voltar-->
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions ="End" VerticalOptions ="End" Padding="30">
                <Button x:Name="Backcon"  Style="{StaticResource BackButton}"                     
                        Text="Voltar"  Clicked="Backcon_Clicked" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

.CS

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ConnectView : ContentPage
{
    public IConnections Conectado;

    public ConnectView ()
    {
      InitializeComponent ();

        Conectado = DependencyService.Get<IConnections>();
        BindingContext = App.CVM;
        MACS_Disponiveis.ItemsSource = App.CVM.BLE_Devices;
//I tried where uses 2 times but didn't work too
        //BindingContext = App.SVM;
        Protocol_Disponivel.ItemsSource = App.SVM.Saved_Protocols;

        if (App.SVM.Saved_Protocols.Count > 0)
            ProtoScreen.IsVisible = true;

        Status_recebimento.MaxLines=1;
    }
    #region Protocol
 
   
    private void NewProtocol_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        App.MDP.Detail = new SetupView();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Aparelhos e MACs
   

    private async void OnSelectionD(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        await DisplayAlert("Selecionado", e.SelectedItem.ToString(), "Ok");
        string a = e.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0, 12);
       
    }

    private void RenomearMAC_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (MenuItem)sender;
        App.CVM.BLE_Devices.Remove(item.CommandParameter.ToString());
    }

    private void RemoverMAC_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (MenuItem)sender;
        App.CVM.BLE_Devices.Remove(item.CommandParameter.ToString());
    }

    
    #endregion

    private void Backcon_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      
        App.MDP.Detail = new StarterView();
    }
}
```

}

My view models are:

```
public class ConnectViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Variables
    public NewStatusCMD newStatusCMD { get; }
    public IConnections All_conn;
    public Connection Bl_Conn;
    private string conectionwaymsg;
    public string bluetoothstatus;
    public string mldplink;
    public string MLDPINBUFF;

    //BLE_Devices is my List there
    public ObservableCollection<string> BLE_Devices;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    public ConnectViewModel()
    {
        Bl_Conn = new Connection();
  
        BLE_Devices = new ObservableCollection<string>();
     
    }
  
    public string Connectionwaymsg
    {
        get { return conectionwaymsg; }
        set
        {
            conectionwaymsg = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); // Realize the event after the new value is informed for adapted.
        }

    }

    public string Mldplink
    {
        get { return mldplink; }
        set
        {
            mldplink = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); // Realize the event after the new value is informed for adapted.
        }

    }
   //Padrão Default
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        if (Mldplink != null)
        {
            MLDPINBUFF = MLDPINBUFF + mldplink;
            mldplink = null;
        }
    }

    private void FillListView()
    {
        var a = All_conn.getMAC();
        for ( int i=0; i < a.Count; i++)  BLE_Devices.Add(a[i]); 
    }

    private void Activation_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        All_conn.ConnectBluetooth();
    }
    private void connection_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        All_conn.ConnectBluetooth();
    }

    }
}
```

and

```
    public class SetupViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public Protocol Protocol_Model;
        public List<Protocol> Saved_Protocols;
        public int[] modelinterval;
        public SetupViewModel()
        {
            modelinterval = new int[16] { 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 };
            Protocol_Model = new Protocol(modelinterval);
            Saved_Protocols = new List<Protocol>();


        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }
}
```

My model are:

```
public class Connection: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string MAC { get; set; }
        private string bluetoothStatus;//private pra não confundir o uso ...
        public string BluetoothStatus
        {
            get { return bluetoothStatus; }
            set
            {
                bluetoothStatus = value;
                App.CVM.newStatusCMD.StatusCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }

        private bool _connvisible;
        public bool ConnVisible
        {
            get { return _connvisible; }
            set
            {
                _connvisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();

            }
        }

        public Connection()
        {
            List<char> Testee;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
```

and

```
public class Protocol
{
    public string Name;
//This is the variable that i tried to use
    public string intervaldescription;
    public int total_Time;
    public string interval_Time;
    public int[] example;
    public int[] intervalBS;

    public Protocol( int[] interval)
    {
        intervalBS = interval;
        intervaldescription = Interval_line(interval);
    }

    private string Interval_line(int[] interval)
    {
        int i;
        string inter_string="";
     
        return inter_string;
    }
}
```

I didn't use a generic MVVM like cross or lite cause my boss use a similar one mine.

Any help

Thanks in advance

Guilherme

Comment: if you are setting the ItemsSource in code then the BindingContext really doesn't matter.  There's no reason you can't assign each ListView it's own ItemsSource.  If that is causing problems then you need to be specific about what those problems are.

Comment: And, possibly not related to this problem, but your layout is a mess.  You have a Grid containing a ScrollView containing multiple nested StackLayouts and ListViews.  Yuck.

Comment: Jason, Thank you to answer me .

Well, when i populate my list view I didn't see my data information in my view ... like not binding ... its different when i dont have a InotifyPropertyChanged ... 

I thought my problem was it, cause that.

Comment: Sorry about my layouts ... :/

Comment: my best suggestion is to use a simple layout with a single LIstView and a TextCell - get that to work first.  Then add another ListView, get that to work.  Then iteratively add more complex layout, more complex cells, etc.  But get the simplest case working first

Comment: Well, I did simulations without 2 listviews and try so solve in parts ...
I notice that my first Listview, didn't work. I try to look more information about it and find some information about Path to correct it. First at all could I make a question? "{Binding .}" ==> Path =. ==> Path =all data.

Comment: "." refers to the entire BindingContext, or in the case of a ListView, the "current" object from the ItemsSource

Comment: How can i select a specific part of my Object into my list ? To use Protocol.Name as a Text in my listview ... i set text="{Binding path=Protocol.Name}" ? Cause I try but there isn't good samples in microsoft website for it. I'm sorry for newbie question, but binding is always confuse :/

Comment: if each Item in your list is a Protocol then just use "{Binding Name}"

Comment: I tried use only "{Binding Name}" and didn't work but I notice that Name is a PropertyPath and in my model class i didn't set as a property (insert {get;set}). After it works.

Thank you for all explanation Jason. If you want ... make a answer with it and I will mark as correct.

Regards !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simple, to use a notify property or binding you need to set a variable as a property. 
To do it you need to add {get;set;} methods in your models because the binding works with a linker/executor to do something.

In that case the worst problem is in Protocol class, because the string inervaldescription didn't have the property methods { get; set;}

```
public class Protocol
{
    public string Name;
    //This is the variable that i tried to use -> IT'S NOT A VARIABLE
    public string intervaldescription{ get; set;}
    public int total_Time;
    public string interval_Time;
    public int[] example;
    public int[] intervalBS;

    public Protocol( int[] interval)
    {
        intervalBS = interval;
        intervaldescription = Interval_line(interval);
    }

    private string Interval_line(int[] interval)
    {
        int i;
        string inter_string="";

        return inter_string;
    }
}
```

As Jason said this code is little mess, so I need to remove the stacklayouts and set almost all the code into a gridlayout.I don't know a way to remove the scrowview but the other stutures could work.

Another information that need to give here is the information about binding context vs Itemsource that Jason give me.

When I use a item source i needn't to use binding context to that struture. So I can use list/collections just notice who is my source.

```
public partial class ConnectView : ContentPage
{
    public IConnections Conectado;

    public ConnectView ()
    {
      InitializeComponent ();

        Conectado = DependencyService.Get<IConnections>();
        BindingContext = App.CVM;
        MACS_Disponiveis.ItemsSource = App.CVM.BLE_Devices;
        Protocol_Disponivel.ItemsSource = App.SVM.Saved_Protocols;

        if (App.SVM.Saved_Protocols.Count > 0)
            ProtoScreen.IsVisible = true;

        Status_recebimento.MaxLines=1;
    }
//.
//.
//.
}
```

Thank you Jason to give the explanations :)

Regards

Guilherme